# Why use more than one type of shell for a single task?

Tags: linux, bash, ksh, csh

I am fairly new to high performance computing, and I've inherited some exiting code for the task I'm working on.  As it stands now, I have a Linux-based HPC using MPI and PBS to queue and run jobs.  What I inherited is python script that dynamically builds and submits a PBS script to the queue, but through the course of a single job, .sh, .csh, and .ksh scripts are called at various points, and most of the shell scripts are very simple, typically less than 10 lines.  Is there any advantage to using multiple different shell flavors in a single job?  Is there any obvious reason that I shouldn't just convert them all to a single flavor?

Comment: It's hard to answer this. Generally, if the scripts are trivial I think it's worth converting them all to one language. It's hard to definitely say that without seeing the scripts, which is why I voted to close this question as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: Unless you can show us the code this probably belongs on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). The main (only?) reason to use multiple languages for any task is that they each excel at solving different *parts* of that task. This seems unlikely in the case of shell scripts, and the situation is probably a historical accident.

Comment: @l0b0 Fair point.  The code is an both huge and a huge mess.  Sharing something intelligible here isn't really doable, but I suspect you're right.  My sense of things is that this has been cobbled together over the course of several iterations and developers.  I'll pose the question over there and see if there are any ideas.

Comment: In my experience there is no good technical reason for using different shells, but there are often non-technical reasons.  One is the "black-box" syndrome, in that if a program does what you want, why rewrite it?  Different people had a fetish about different shells.  I was brought-up on csh purely because it was the default on Sun (the guy who wrote csh founded Sun), fortunately I was cured a long time ago.  ksh was far superior but was not open source until (I think) 2000, so bash was used on Linux.  So the reason for the different languages is probably historical.

Comment: If you decide to convert them I suggest you first document what they do generally in a language-independent way.  Then write new code using the documentation, line-by-line conversion is rarely a good idea.  Also consider a system with fewer scripts using a more powerful language like python.  However always remember the adage *if it ain't broke don't fix it*.

Comment: My guess would also be a bunch of developers each writing their own way. Before you decide to rewrite everything in a more decent way, consider the life cycle. Do you expect a lot of changes in the code the next 5 years, or are you only trying to keep it running until someone shuts off the electricity?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any advantage to using multiple different shell flavors in a single job?

Highly unlikely.

The primary differences between these shells, especially at this scale, will simply be their syntax. In particular, csh uses a more "C-like" syntax for certain control structures like `if` and `for`; ksh will be more similar to the Bash syntax you're probably familiar with. Their feature sets are essentially identical.

The most likely reason that these interpreters were used is simple: the scripts were written by different authors long ago, before consensus had emerged around the use of the Bash shell. (If they're old enough, it's even possible that Bash didn't exist at the time -- csh and ksh were released in 1978 and 1983, whereas Bash didn't come around until 1989.)

Comment: Performance can be a significant difference -- genuine David Korn ksh93 is (unlike its various clones) **far** faster than bash to execute (and within a single base-10 order of magnitude of awk). But then, if you're going to mix languages to avoid implementing a tight inner loop in a slow shell, why wouldn't you take that 10x performance difference and use awk, or use an even faster/more modern language like Go or Julia? :)

Comment: (...that said, I wouldn't ever advice csh for use by anyone, ever; it has the same kind of inattention to good design that plagues PHP).

Comment: ...also, until bash 4.x (which has closed the gaps quite effectively), ksh93 had a substantial lead in features -- associative arrays, namevars, etc; I can think of substantial non-performance-related reasons to prefer ksh93 over a pre-4.0 bash.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Remember that this is in the context of a couple of scripts that are "typically less than 10 lines". I doubt that either speed or features are a major consideration here!

Comment: Floating point can also be an issue, even in a small script.  ksh93 supports floating point, the others do not.